# ASP.NET change text with no page refresh on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've found a couple other threads containing the same questions, but none of them had an understandable answer. I am supposed to make client side changes, but that is only possible in the .ascx file and if for instance i want to call a function to calculate something and then display it with no page refresh that is not possible :( any easy solutions?

Comment: You could use `updatepanel` to perform some action without page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

With jquery, you can replace the contents of any existing HTML element using the [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) function.  For example,

```
$("#MyDiv").html("Here is the new text.");
```

Since the function takes HTML as an input, you can even set the style if you want:

```
$("#MyDiv").html("Here is some text.  <DIV class='foo'>Here is some more text in a different style.</DIV>");
```

You can also add new elements using [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/), like this:

```
$("#MyDiv").append("<p>Even more text</p>");
```

To do this upon a button click, you would use the [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) function.  So your code would look something like this:

```
$("#MyButton").click(function() {
    $("#MyDiv").html("You just clicked a button!");
});
```